# Pulling individual integer value from hexadecimal value

Tags: c

Here is my hex code:

```
42 4D C6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 76 00 00 00 28 00 
00 00 0A 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 01 00 04 00 00 00 
00 00 50 00 00 00 12 0B 00 00 12 0B 00 00 10 00 
00 00 10 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 FF 00 00 00 00 
42 00 5A 5A 84 00 00 00 FF 00 FF 00 FF 00 00 FF 
FF 00 08 FF FF 00 5A FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF 
FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF FF 00 FF FF 
FF 00 FF FF FF 00 92 59 00 16 47 00 00 00 25 90 
01 64 61 00 00 00 59 90 11 64 61 00 00 00 99 00 
16 48 11 00 00 00 90 01 64 61 11 00 00 00 00 16 
64 61 00 00 00 00 01 16 46 10 09 00 00 00 11 64 
41 00 99 00 00 00 16 64 11 09 95 00 00 00 66 48 
10 09 53 00 00 00
```

I know that the pixel "assignment" starts with the first line being (10 pixels wide):

```
92 59 00 16 47 00 00 00
```

I need to count how many times each colour is in the image, but I am unable to pull the individual integer value (ie: just the 9, then just the 2, then just the 5, and so on).  The only value I am able to pull is "92" then "59" then "00"...

This is my code for that segment (the offset is 118 and the total hex values remaining are 80):

```
 int nbr_each[NBRCOLOURS];
    int ch, pixel;

            fseek(fptr, 118, SEEK_SET);
            for (count = 0; count < 81; count++)
            {
                pixel = fgetc(fptr);
                nbr_each[pixel] = nbr_each[pixel] + 1;
            }
```

Comment: Good luck working out the question

Comment: How many bits does one integer have?

Comment: I don't know. Not sure how to find out either.

Comment: Is this close for you? `pixel = fgetc(fptr); left_hex_digit = pixel/16; rightt_hex_digit = pixel%16;`

Answer (score 0):

fgetc will get you the individual characters.

```
first = fgetc(fptr);   // '9'
second = fgetc(fptr);  // '2'
space = fgetc(fptr);   // ' '
```

Then convert each digit to a number 0..9 by subtracting off '0':

```
first -= '0';
second -= '0';
```

Then to count each digit, something like this:

```
nbr_each[first]++;
nbr_each[second]++;
```